# Continuity of a Sup function. Edited

Tags: real-analysis

If $f:A\rightarrow B$ is continuous, A is a compact set of some metric $Y$, how dows one show $||f||$ is continuous, 
...if it even is continuous. I am inducing that it is since if a real functions is continuous, then its absolute value function is as well.

Comment: What is $\sup \|f(x)\|_Y$ defined as a function over? The space $C(A,B)$ of continuous functions from $A$ to $B$?

Comment: the set of x's in A.

Comment: ...with the supremum taken over all $x\in A$?

Comment: sorry, Alex, I edited the question.

Comment: @capItan: Do you mean 'show the function $x \mapsto ||f(x)||$ is continuous'?

Comment: @ copper.hat: yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the triangle inequality, you have $||x|| \leq ||x-y|| + ||y||$, and similarly with $x,y$ reversed. From this you can conclude that $|\;||x||-||y||\;| \leq ||x-y||$, ie, the norm is continuous. Now apply this, replacing $x$ by $f(x)$ and $y$ by $f(y)$, and use continuity of $f$.